# scala - convert tuplen of long datatype to Array[Long]

Tags: scala

I get the counts of dataframe columns from spark to scala variable as below

```
scala> col_counts
res38: (Long, Long, Long) = (3,3,0)

scala>
```

Now, I want to convert this to Array(3,3,0).  I'm doing a roundabout way like

```
scala> col_counts.toString.replaceAll("""\)|\(""","").split(",")
res47: Array[String] = Array(3, 3, 0)

scala>
```

But it looks ugly. Is there an elegant way of getting it? I'm looking for a generic solution to convert any n - Long tuple to Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
val tuple :(Long,Long,Long) = (3,3,0)
tuple.productIterator.toArray
```

Comment: Result is `Array[Any]`. Not terribly useful. To get the `Long` back you'd have to cast. Seldom recommended.